# Unable to upgrade due EFI partition problem

Tags: 16.04, boot, partitioning, uefi

When I'm trying to upgrade my computer with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS, this error appears every single time I try the process:

> EFI System Partition (ESP) not usable
>   Your EFI System Partition (ESP) is not mounted at /boot/efi. Please ensure that it is properly configured and try again.

In the taskbar, there is a unit of 256 MB with in file explorer is named as "bce08984-d061-4aa7-96cd-2115ea1e8956", that appeared suddenly when I upgraded last time from 14.04 to 16.04.

Please help me, my computer isn't dual boot, and I don't have another machine available.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I was reading that there is some data in the fstab file that can be changed to make it work. This is the content of my file:

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/mapper/pdc_bciefbajg2 /boot ext2 defaults,noauto 0 2
/dev/mapper/pdc_bciefbajg1 /boot/efi vfat defaults,noauto 0 1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0

Comment: Do not post in comments. Post in original question and add formatting so it is readable. But it looks like you have an UEFI install using LVM. Is it also encrypted? Do you have good backups, which all uses should have, but many do not.

Comment: No, I don't have backups, and isn't encrypted...

Comment: When I open the said unit from the task bar, I see inside two folders, one called "efi" and another "grub", and a bunch of other files. Someones have an icon that looks like an exe file, like "memtest86+.elf" and "vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic", and others look like plain text files, some called "abi-3.13.0-109-generic", "abi-4.4.0-31-generic" and the list continues… There is also files in a box shaped icon, like "initrd.img-3.13.0-109-generic" and "initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic". Can I erase them, or they are important files?

Comment: I see one of the folders is named like one of the directions shown by the error, but there is no boot folder in this unit that, as I said, appeared suddenly

Comment: The files in the ESP - efi system partition are essential. But 3.13 kernel is from 14.04 which is now obsolete.  The ESP is for the UEFI part of grub. The rest of grub and boot files are in your LVM volumes. The 4.4 kernel is from 16.04. Often better to just do clean install & restore from backups. Especially if multiple older installs, so you have lots of cruft if you have not housecleaned. And some others have posted issues with upgrades & LVM partitions. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition/339621#339621

Comment: I agree with @oldfred: take a full backup of all your data files, reinstall, restore files is the surest way to get this sorted.  You could try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) before you do all that ***after you've taken a backup!***.  **;-)**

Comment: I decided to make a new installation (formatting as my friends says), but first tried with a virtual machine on VirtualBox based in some recommendations of some friends and YouTube videos, and I'm getting problems with it, because I got stuck with only having 4 GB of "free space" when there is a lot more I assigned for the virtual disk (like 250 GB, after all, I'm going to erase it when reinstalling Ubuntu). I'm really annoyed this seems too difficult to even make testing… Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I have already backed up my data on a pendrive, if something goes wrong, and I have a disk with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (I got a magazine with it, and there is where I got the way to install the virtual machine). I used to had a friend of mine who was very used to help me with Ubuntu, but he is now in another country, and I can't talk with him too often because he connects on midnight, and I'm studying, so I can't take a whole night without sleep because I'm going to be like a zombi in the morning XD